# Which machine learning algorithm can be used for traffic prediction using images from Google Maps?

Tags: machine-learning, learning

I am doing a traffic prediction project.
I am using data from Google Maps. I'm collecting maps of different location and analyzing them. I am converting the maps to images, analyzing the image, and predict traffic.

Which machine learning algorithm can be used for this prediction?

Comment: Add more description: What exactly you are trying to predict? How your dataset looks like (what's the example and what's the groundtruth)? These things are necessary to select the algorithm ...

Comment: I agree with @AntonioJurić you need to add a lot more detail. It sounds like you want to do "traffic" but with existing analysis of traffic already done (i.e. google maps). Also, you should be aware that most "true" work on traffic is actually done with applied statistics, it's not always an algorithmic problem to be solved. Nice, old-fashioned, applied stats is actually quite effective for the majority of work with traffic.